# React Native Wait All Image Prefetch Done

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I'm trying to prefetch multiple image before navigating to another screen, but returnedStudents all undefined.

```
prepareStudentImages = async (students) => {
    let returnedStudents = students.map(student => {
        Image.prefetch(student.image)
        .then((data) => {
            ...
        })
        .catch((data) => {
            ...
        })
        .finally(() => {
            return student;
        });
    });

    await console.log(returnedStudents); // ----> all items undefined
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of things to fix with this:

1) Your [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function does not return anything. This is why your console log is `undefined`.

2) Once your map functions work, you are logging an array of promises. To deal with multiple promises (an array), you can use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

So I think to fix this, you can do:

```
prepareStudentImages = async (students) => {
  const returnedStudents = students.map(student => 
    Image.prefetch(student.image)
      .then((data) => {
          ...
      })
      .catch((data) => {
          ...
      })
      .finally(() => {
          return student
      })
  )

  console.log(returnedStudents) // log the promise array

  const result = await Promise.all(returnedStudents) // wait until all asyncs are complete
  console.log(result) // log the results of each promise in an array

  return result
}
```

Comment: I think you miss an await before Promise.all

Comment: `return student` in `finally` doesn't return to the map() function? Btw, I don't see any different between my and your map function.

Comment: @quirimmo Added await but still no luck, still getting undefineds.

Comment: Ah I see, we need to add return: `return Image.prefetch` without removing return in `finally`.

Comment: Once you added `return` and `await` in the answer I'll accept.

Comment: Sorry missed the await. But you don't need to add the return, just remove the braces.

Comment: Oh I missed that difference. Thanks.